# Cannot access SD card on WINC1500

Tags: sd-card

I have a WINC1500 shield and have the Wi-Fi side working fine. I want to do some datalogging to the SD card and am having trouble getting it running. I have bought a 16 GB Sandisk card and inserted it. I have added the SD library, `SD.h` is included. However `SD.begin()` fails. I have a Mega2560 card (from Elegoo) so should be able to run the SD and wifi at the same time? Do I need to pass a parameter to `SD.begin()`?

The code below always prints "Card failed to initialise, or not present".

```
if(!SD.begin())
{
    Serial.println("Card failed to initialise, or not present");
}
else
{
    Serial.println("Card initialised ok");
}
```

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoWiFiShield#toc9

Comment: as @Juraj obliquely pointed out try 'SD.begin(4)'

Comment: and set pin 53 to output and set pin 10 high if you don't begin() the WiFi library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to pass a parameter to SD.begin()?

Yes, you need to pass the Chip-Select (CS/SS) pin number. What number depends on how you have it hooked up, the default is 10. (*yours might be 4*)

n.b. according to the docs a standard arduino can't use the WiFi, and the SD at the same time; presumably the mega has enough memory.

Comment: [these docs](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-winc1500-wifi-shield-for-arduino/overview)

Comment: Thanks. It does need to be 4 for the WINC1500 with no jumpers cut. And yes the mega has enough memory for both.